# Chrome Elements

Tags: google-chrome

When using elements, in the resource tab, there use to be a chart that showed the time it took for file to load on a page and also the size of that file. That chart is no longer there. I see it in Safari but it's not in Chrome anymore. Was something changed or is there something I need to do to enable it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for the [Network tab](http://code.google.com/chrome/devtools/docs/network.html)? It was [recently added](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/02/chrome-developer-tools-back-to-basics.html). Note that the developer tools must be open before the page is loaded for information to show up.

[image: Chrome Network tab]